# Не отображаются кириллические символы при передаче параметра в .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Если вставить код непосредственно в обработчик - все работает корректно.

```
<input value="Нажми меня"  onclick="document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'лалала'" type="button">
```

Но стоит вставить его в подключаемый `.js` файл и вызвать при нажатии на кнопку, и вместо кириллических символов - квадратики.

```
$("#testbtn").click(function() {document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'лалала'});
```

Загадка для меня. В чем разница?

Comment: в кодировке подключаемого файла.

Comment: @Grundy Действительно. Спасибо!